# require_once() allowing localhost URL

Tags: php, linux, apache, tomcat, php-java-bridge

I am working on implementation of [php/java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/webapp.php) on a linux server.

One of the main requirement for this to work is including tomcat's url in php's [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) function. I understand I can do this by  turning on the **allow_url_include** in php.ini file. However, I am worried about the security.

- Is there anyway I can restrict the require_once() to localhost or specific urls only?
- Or, any other workaround that you may know?

> I am using apache2.x (php5) on localhost
>
> Tomcat url on port 8080, so http: //localhost:8080/JavaBridge. (On Debian 6.0.4(Squeeze))

EDIT: The url I am trying to include is php/java bridge library. The contents looks like this in the regular browser: http://pastebin.com/Kk9qCkMV

Comment: What exactly is contained in the url you are requesting?

Comment: The url contains the The PHP/Java Bridge's PHP library. 
Here is the contents if I directly access that url in the browser http://pastebin.com/Kk9qCkMV

Answer (score 0):

You could try ...

```
eval(file_get_contents('http: //localhost:8080/JavaBridge'));
```

Comment: I tried using the eval function. Got: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/m3.php(4) : eval()'d code on line 1 "

Same url works perfectly fine with require_once().